# Even i declared node.js still got an error while executing Visual Studio Code ,how can i solve this problem?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Even i declared node.js still got an error while executing Visual Studio Code ,how can i solve this problem? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L0Zg.png)

Comment: Please post your error traceback as formatted code and not an image.

Comment: BFK because you are not set the environment path of node js in your system that's why you are getting this error

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pqqr.png)

node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: edit your question, not add an answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).